# Can anyone explain me how does this Flat Assembler code works?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, fasm

I am trying to learn me making GUI programs in assembly. I downloaded Flat Assembler and started to read the example programs. There I found this code.
This is 64 bit code in assembly (fasm) for Windows. It makes empty window. But there was very few comments in It, so It's hard for me to understand what's going on. I commented here which parts I don't understand.

```
format PE64 GUI 5.0
entry start

include 'win64a.inc'

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

  library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
          user32,'USER32.DLL'

  include 'api\kernel32.inc'
  include 'api\user32.inc'

section '.data' data readable writeable

  _title TCHAR 'Win64 program template',0
  _class TCHAR 'FASMWIN64',0
  _error TCHAR 'Startup failed.',0

  wc WNDCLASSEX sizeof.WNDCLASSEX,0,WindowProc,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,COLOR_BTNFACE+1,NULL,_class,NULL

  msg MSG

section '.text' code readable executable

  start:
        sub     rsp,8           ; Make stack dqword aligned

        invoke  GetModuleHandle,0 ;GetModuleHandle,0?
        mov     [wc.hInstance],rax ;wc.hInstance?
        invoke  LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION ;LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION?
        mov     [wc.hIcon],rax ;wc.hIcon?
        mov     [wc.hIconSm],rax ;ec.hIconSm?
        invoke  LoadCursor,0,IDC_ARROW ;LoadCursor,0,IDC_ARROW?
        mov     [wc.hCursor],rax ;wc.hCursor?
        invoke  RegisterClassEx,wc ;RegisterClassEx,wc?
        test    rax,rax ;test?
        jz      error

        invoke  CreateWindowEx,0,_class,_title,WS_VISIBLE+WS_DLGFRAME+WS_SYSMENU,128,128,256,192,NULL,NULL,[wc.hInstance],NULL
        test    rax,rax
        jz      error

  msg_loop: ;What does this function?
        invoke  GetMessage,msg,NULL,0,0
        cmp     eax,1
        jb      end_loop
        jne     msg_loop
        invoke  TranslateMessage,msg
        invoke  DispatchMessage,msg
        jmp     msg_loop

  error:
        invoke  MessageBox,NULL,_error,NULL,MB_ICONERROR+MB_OK

  end_loop:
        invoke  ExitProcess,[msg.wParam]

proc WindowProc uses rbx rsi rdi, hwnd,wmsg,wparam,lparam ;?

; Note that first four parameters are passed in registers,
; while names given in the declaration of procedure refer to the stack
; space reserved for them - you may store them there to be later accessible
; if the contents of registers gets destroyed. This may look like:
;       mov     [hwnd],rcx
;       mov     [wmsg],edx
;       mov     [wparam],r8
;       mov     [lparam],r9

        cmp     edx,WM_DESTROY
        je      .wmdestroy
  .defwndproc: ;What does this?
        invoke  DefWindowProc,rcx,rdx,r8,r9
        jmp     .finish
  .wmdestroy:
        invoke  PostQuitMessage,0
        xor     eax,eax
  .finish:
        ret

endp
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're asking about. For example, `invoke  GetModuleHandle,0 ;?` -- is it that you don't know what `invoke` is, that you don't know what `GetModuleHandle` is, that you don't know what the `,0` means, or that you don't know what the `,0` is for, etc?

Comment: I know 'invoke' but I don't know what is the next thing. In this case 'GetModuleHandle,0'

Comment: As explained in [the documentation for `invoke`](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32), "The stdcall calls directly the procedure specified by the first argument using the STDCALL calling convention. The rest of arguments passed to macro define the parameters to procedure... The invoke macro does the same, however it calls the procedure indirectly, through the pointer labelled by the first argument."